# Convert text input into a select with values from a table

Tags: jquery

I have an ordering website where I can't edit the HTML structure unfortunately (CMS).

For some products, they are available in multiple quantities e.g. 250, 500 etc.

At the moment we have a text input where the user types in the quantity they need. However we would like to restrict them to only select the quantities that are available. So instead of a free type text input, we would like a select drop down.

On our page we have a table of the quantities and their prices e.g. (PROD201 being the product code which is automatically assigned into the ID's)

```
<table summary="Product discounts" class="nc discounts">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th id="q-prod201" axis="quantity" scope="row">Quantity</th>
    <th id="q0-prod201" axis="250" scope="col">250</th>
    <th id="q1-prod201" axis="500" scope="col">500</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="price-row">
    <th id="p-prod201" axis="discount-price" scope="row">Unit Price</th>
    <td headers="q0-prod201">£0.00</td>
    <td headers="q1-prod201">£0.00</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the current text input...

```
<input type="text" name="basket:_new:quantity" class="qty quantity" id="quantity-prod201" value="250" size="3" />
```

I would like to try and extract the quantity values in the table, and convert the text input to a select using those values.

I can target the quantity values based on the scope="col" attribute (as that seems to be the unique identifier)...

```
$("#product .discounts thead th[scope='col']").map(function() {
  var $row = $(this);
  return { 
    scope: $row.attr('scope'), 
    text: $row.text()
  };
}).get();
```

But I'm not sure how to convert those in to a select and replace the existing input.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a select element and add the options:

```
var select = $("<select>");
$("#product .discounts thead th[scope='col']").each(function (index, element) {
    select.append($("<option>" + $(element).text() + "</option>"));
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/G8cCq/1/)